# R How to create a loop to subset dataframes for each country

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have five dataframes : t1, t2, t3, t4, t5. All the dataframes (they have the same structure just some values differ) have a variable "country" with the same number of attributes.

Essentially I want to get a number of variables N : 
For each country and dataset => one variable.

My code looks like that right now, but it is very tedious and long:

```
t1.COUNTRY1 <- subset(t1, SA0100="COUNTRY1")
t2.COUNTRY1 <- subset(t2, SA0100="COUNTRY1")
t3.COUNTRY1 <- subset(t3, SA0100="COUNTRY1")
t4.COUNTRY1 <- subset(t4, SA0100="COUNTRY1")
t5.COUNTRY1 <- subset(t5, SA0100="COUNTRY1")
t1.COUNTRY2 <- subset(t1, SA0100="COUNTRY2")
t2.COUNTRY2 <- subset(t2, SA0100="COUNTRY2")
...
```

---

**dataset t1**, the others look the same

```
    SA0100    DA1000   DA2100  RA0300
1   COUNTRY1  40000    45666    45
2   COUNTRY1  25456    78888    36
3   COUNTRY1  45666    12547    18
4   COUNTRY1  41255    58796    23 
5   COUNTRY1  78992    32589    28
6   COUNTRY2  12558    25556    22
7   COUNTRY2  96542    65478    78
```

I have tried to use a loop but I did not manage to get anything and I do not see how to use the lapply() function in this particular case.

Can you help me?

Comment: What should `t1.COUNTRY1` look like? Do you want to append all of the data so it is one long vector? Or is it some kind of summary statistic?

Comment: @John Paul t1.COUNTRY1 is a dataframe (with three variables) which will be used for data analysis. Do I answer to your question?

Comment: @BrunoGG Please show an example dataset to have an idea

Comment: @akrun : I updated the question. Can I develop more? Do you need more elements?

Comment: @BrunoGG I posted a solution.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to create `objects` (I would prefer to have it in a list rather than clutter with lots of objects), you could do:

```
 list2env(unlist(lapply(mget(ls(pattern="t\\d+")), 
          function(x) split(x, x$SA0100)), recursive=FALSE), 
                                              envir=.GlobalEnv)


 t1.COUNTRY1
 #    SA0100 DA1000 DA2100 RA0300
 #1 COUNTRY1  40000  45666     45
 #2 COUNTRY1  25456  78888     36
 #3 COUNTRY1  45666  12547     18
 #4 COUNTRY1  41255  58796     23
 #5 COUNTRY1  78992  32589     28

  t3.COUNTRY2
  #  SA0100 DA1000 DA2100 RA0300
  #1 COUNTRY2  12558  25556     22
  #4 COUNTRY2  12558  25556     22
```

#### data

```
 t1 <- structure(list(SA0100 = c("COUNTRY1", "COUNTRY1", "COUNTRY1", 
 "COUNTRY1", "COUNTRY1", "COUNTRY2", "COUNTRY2"), DA1000 = c(40000L, 
 25456L, 45666L, 41255L, 78992L, 12558L, 96542L), DA2100 = c(45666L, 
 78888L, 12547L, 58796L, 32589L, 25556L, 65478L), RA0300 = c(45L, 
 36L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 22L, 78L)), .Names = c("SA0100", "DA1000", 
 "DA2100", "RA0300"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

  t2 <- structure(list(SA0100 = c("COUNTRY2", "COUNTRY2", "COUNTRY1"), 
  DA1000 = c(96542L, 96542L, 45666L), DA2100 = c(65478L, 65478L, 
  12547L), RA0300 = c(78L, 78L, 18L)), .Names = c("SA0100", 
 "DA1000", "DA2100", "RA0300"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

  t3 <- structure(list(SA0100 = c("COUNTRY2", "COUNTRY1", "COUNTRY1", 
  "COUNTRY2", "COUNTRY1"), DA1000 = c(12558L, 78992L, 41255L, 12558L, 
  40000L), DA2100 = c(25556L, 32589L, 58796L, 25556L, 45666L), 
  RA0300 = c(22L, 28L, 23L, 22L, 45L)), .Names = c("SA0100", 
  "DA1000", "DA2100", "RA0300"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This script uses a loop and subsets the countries in a list called country, assuming that country 1 appears in t1, country 2 in t2 etc. In case countries also appear in other datasets (e.g., country 1 in dataset 2) then the last line of the script should be changed (changing tcp in t1, t2 etc.).

```
a=5 # number of iterations, datasets t1:t5

tch<-paste0(rep("t",each=a), c(1:a))
cch<-paste0(rep("Country",each=a), c(1:a))
country<-list()

for (i in 1:a)
{tcp<-get(tch[i])
country[[i]] <- (subset(tcp, SAO100==cch[i]))}
```